# Ruby rbenv ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ruby-build

I want to install `Ruby 3.1.2` using rbenv but for some indescribable reason I end up with the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.4 using ruby-build 20220713)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/bw/rs138g1n5zv_qwn7_7kggc9r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20220719230321.35067.BRya3b
Results logged to /var/folders/bw/rs138g1n5zv_qwn7_7kggc9r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20220719230321.35067.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/include
```

What I tried so far was:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv

$ rbenv install 3.1.2
```

And I ended up with the above error. I already tried to:

- reinstall rbenv
- re-install ruby-build
- install first ruby 3.1.0 (the same error)

and below:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` --with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` --with-libyaml-dir=`brew --prefix libyaml`" rbenv install 3.1.2
```

With the same result.

My rbenv version:

```
$ rbenv --version
rbenv 1.2.0
```

What I missed?

Comment: Please post the full log file, not just the last 10 lines. More clues could be in the full file.

Comment: What does `xcode-select -p` say?

Comment: I don't know what happened but the old fashioned way worked - reboot Mac